# Is there any algorithm book that teaches like Head First series?

Tags: java, books, algorithms

As a Java programmer I need to learn algorithms (for programming Challenges). I read some Head First Series (JAVA owned by me) and they are pretty brain friendly. So I was wondering is there any algorithm book that will be simple to understand and also goes to the crux of each algo.

Comment: Relevant: ['Head First' Style Data Structures & Algorithms Book? on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455627/head-first-style-data-structures-algorithms-book)

Comment: Relevant: [Is there no book on algorithms that is easy to read, like the Head First series? on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331105/is-there-no-book-on-algorithms-that-is-easy-to-read-like-the-head-first-series)

Comment: Not a book, but a great and potentially easy-to-understand resource similar to Head First:  https://class.coursera.org/algo . Registration is closed, but they will probably repeat the class.

Comment: It's always difficult to find similar question and I end up putting a duplicate question. Please vote up for any book before this question is closed by someone. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a canonical reference on algorithm design?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/69981/is-there-a-canonical-reference-on-algorithm-design)

Answer (score 2):

I personally like the book [Algorithms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/032157351X) by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne very much. The book has very beautiful illustrations show how different algorithms work, and also provides very practical examples. You can get some feeling about the quality of the book by visit the companion [website](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/).

Answer (score 1):

Personally I learned with [Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=algorithm%20design%20manual&hl=en&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS455US455&prmd=imvnsb&resnum=4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&ix=seb&ion=1&biw=1366&bih=643&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=18093835486552863414&sa=X&ei=e19wT4fNBoeTtwf4t7ibBg&ved=0CFgQ8gIwAA) by Steven S.Skiena, and currently use [Algorithms In a Nutshell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/059651624X) to as a quick reference for algorithms I don't implement to much. Algorithms In a Nutshell uses both Java, Ruby, C, and C++ for its code examples but being a Java coder you shouldn't have too much trouble reading the C/C++ code snippets. And even if you couldn't read them, they aren't essential for understanding the algorithm, a full description is available purely based on text and pictures.

Comment: I read [here](http://www.flipkart.com/algorithm-design-manual-8184898657/p/itmdyuv8cfedy3nd?pid=9788184898651&_l=z0zreNTXOpiPJsqCSh1kaQ--&_r=TgA%20qV2%20NUXYVCCmE36rHg--&ref=367f6716-352d-4ec4-9296-625c6c542d36) that it's not good for beginners. Now I am in dilemma. Please help

Comment: Huh, I disagree, and the people on SO seem to agree with me, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689222/the-algorithm-design-manual-by-steven-skiena-vs-introduction-to-algorithms-by-t

Answer (score -1):

I found this

- http://www.amazon.co.uk/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Michael-Goodrich/dp/0471738840/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1335693080&sr=8-3

to be very helpful during my second year at the university.